# Missing Partial - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I'm a Ruby beginner and I'm currently trying to write a redmine plugin which takes the header tag and turns it into a link.

For some reason my Redmine always throws the following error:

> Showing
> C:/Users/user/RubymineProjects/redmine_ma/redmine/app/views/layouts/base.html.erb where line #15 raised:
>
> Missing partial plugins/linked_slogan/app/views/_linkify_slogans with
> {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb,
> :builder, :raw, :ruby, :rsb]}.
>
> Searched in:
> "C:/Users/user/RubymineProjects/redmine_ma/redmine/plugins/redmine_user_default_group/app/views"
>
> "C:/Users/user/RubymineProjects/redmine_ma/redmine/plugins/redmine_default_private_comments/app/views"
>
> "C:/Users/user/RubymineProjects/redmine_ma/redmine/plugins/linked_slogan/app/views"
>
> "C:/Users/user/RubymineProjects/redmine_ma/redmine/app/views"

This is what my hook file looks like:

```
class Linked_slogan < Redmine::Hook::ViewListener
  render_on :view_layouts_base_html_head,
            :partial => 'linkify_slogans'
end
```

I've made sure that the file starts with an "_" (underscore), I tried writing the full path into the :partial => '' or just bits of it and nothing seems to work.

Full path to the partial "C:\Users\user\RubymineProjects\redmine_ma\redmine\plugins\linked_slogan\app\view‌​s\_linkify_slogans.html.erb"

Comment: Can you post the path the the actual partial? Like, where does the file sit?

Comment: C:\Users\user\RubymineProjects\redmine_ma\redmine\plugins\linked_slogan\app\views\

Comment: Can you post the FULL path (including the filename)?

Comment: C:\Users\user\RubymineProjects\redmine_ma\redmine\plugins\linked_slogan\app\view‌​s\\_linkify_slogans.html.erb

(I also wrote that in the OP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed workstations and now it's working for some reason. I have no clue what happened.